# Weird crash on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I randomly cause crash during testing my app on an iPhone 4s.  When i launch XCode i go to Windows->Devices and find crash log. Please take a look:

```
Incident Identifier: 205056B8-F2D7-4A39-9C12-6187B2578DBD
CrashReporter Key:   7af6225512c44ff8981f2fe467e30203e30163f7
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             medsolutions [3180]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C38BF017-83AD-4F40-9A1D-08078974B93F/medsolutions.app/medsolutions
Identifier:          ru.medsolutions.mes
Version:             108 (3.0.7)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-06-10 13:18:52.909 +0300
Launch Time:         2016-06-10 13:10:16.009 +0300
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F70)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc4b132 __exceptionPreprocess + 122
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39cdbc72 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2bc4ae40 -[NSException raise] + 4
3   Foundation                      0x2c95c592 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 258
4   Foundation                      0x2c8c383a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 198
5   medsolutions                    0x000e88c2 0xd0000 + 100546
6   medsolutions                    0x00487e98 0xd0000 + 3899032
7   UIKit                           0x2f555e1c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 472
8   UIKit                           0x2f555ede -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 50
9   UIKit                           0x2f54a9be -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2022
10  UIKit                           0x2f3592b6 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 182
11  UIKit                           0x2f282c16 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 542
12  QuartzCore                      0x2eca1440 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 124
13  QuartzCore                      0x2ec9cc90 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 356
14  QuartzCore                      0x2ec9cb18 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
15  QuartzCore                      0x2ec9c4ba CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 218
16  QuartzCore                      0x2ec9c2aa CA::Transaction::commit() + 430
17  QuartzCore                      0x2ecefab8 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 520
18  IOMobileFramebuffer             0x3391cbfe IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 86
19  IOKit                           0x2cbc3d08 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 252
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc00550 __CFMachPortPerform + 128
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc10a46 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc109e2 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 342
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2bc0f004 __CFRunLoopRun + 1604
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2bb5a99c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
25  CoreFoundation                  0x2bb5a7ae CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
26  GraphicsServices                0x333331a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
27  UIKit                           0x2f2e5690 UIApplicationMain + 1436
28  medsolutions                    0x002f83ac 0xd0000 + 2261932
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a283aaa tlv_initializer + 2
```

And more..

How to figure out what exactly did crash? Thanks

Comment: In Xcode go to the breakpoints tab. Add an exception breakpoint. Run your app, make it crash. It will show the line of code causing the crash.

Comment: @Fogmeister i cant reproduce that crash again.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log, that will convert the `medsolutions` lines from memory locations to the section of the application that's causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one of your cells has unexpected connection in a xib file. For example, you added property with UILabel type and connect label from the xib to it property. After that you've delete property from cell's source and forget to remove connection in the xib.
And you have different cells (with different classes) in the table, sometimes (for example, when you have a network connection problem) you try to display cell with the problem and get crash.
I think you should check all your cell's xibs and subview's xibs to check their to problems with connections.

Comment: Can you symbolicate the crash log?

Comment: This problem lies in a cell's creation method or in a cellWillDisplay... method, without these methods no one can help  you. And from this crash I can't understand name of a owner view controller or class of the cell.